# Custom video plugin for videos in TinyMCE overwrites video tag

Tags: javascript, video, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have a custom plugin that opens a list of videos and inserts a video.
The main goal is to remove the download button while keeping this video interface.

Online it was said that `controlsList="nodownload"` should do the trick..

```
    tinymce.PluginManager.add("videoPlugin", function (editor, url) {
      editor.ui.registry.addButton("videoPlugin", {
        text: "Videos",
        onAction: function () {
          // Here you can open a dialog, make an AJAX request, etc.
          // The key point is to get the necessary information (like file url)
          // and call editor.insertContent() function.
          openVideoDialog();
        },
      });

      function openVideoDialog() {
        console.log(videoList);
        return editor.windowManager.open({
          title: "Videos",
          body: {
            type: "panel",
            items: [
              {
                type: "selectbox",
                name: "video",
                label: "Video",
                items: videoList,
              },
            ],
          },
          buttons: [
            {
              type: "cancel",
              text: "Close",
            },
            {
              type: "submit",
              text: "Insert",
              primary: true,
            },
          ],
          onSubmit: function (api) {
            var data = api.getData();

            // Insert the audio player to the editor
            editor.insertContent(
              '<video width="560" height="315" src="' +
                data.video +
                '" controls controlsList="nodownload" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></video>'
            );
            api.close();
          },
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

However after inserting a video using the plugin the video is inserted with this embed code

`<video src="https://storagexyz.com/videos/video.mp4" controls="controls" width="560" height="315"></video>`

Instead of
`<video width="560" height="315" src="https://storagexyz.com/videos/video.mp4" controls controlsList="nodownload" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></video>`

Why is that and how to fix?